# Is there any well known project to VBify C and make C as RAD language?

Tags: c, vb.net, rad

I have two questions:

`Question #1`: Is there any well known project to **VBify**  C? **VBify** here means **to make it as easy as in VB.NET** and to make C well supported in IDE just like VB.NET, i.e. with following features: word completion, function's argument description and everything just as with VB.NET development using Visual Studio.

`Question #2`: Is there any well known effort to make C as **RAD (Rapid Application Development)** language?

Comment: What do you mean by RAD? I hope it is not about something as mundane as visual GUI design.

Comment: When I read "VBify C" I had to suppress an involuntary shudder.

Comment: If you have two questions, post two questions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for Visual C++ 2010 Express?

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

This allows you to do C++ programming, so you "just" need to stay within plain C.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, any good C IDE should provide that functionality for, at the very least, standard C. I haven't done C programming in a while, doing mostly C++ and Java development, but I would look at IDEs such as NetBeans or Eclipse with the necessary plugins to support C development. [Wikipedia also lists a number of other C and C++ IDEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B).

As for your second question, language has nothing to do with Rapid Application Development. RAD is a process methodology that emphasizes rapid prototyping over up-front planning and design.  Although not explicitly about Rapid Application Development, Steve McConnell wrote a book about achieving shorter schedules and higher quality products - [Rapid Development: Taming Wild Software Schedules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556159005). There is one section where RAD is explicitly mentioned, and it's described as "a collection of practices" that "doesn't apply to any kind of unique software".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Embarcadero's C++ Builder.  It takes the powerful, easy-to-use Delphi IDE and standard libraries, including the VCL, (the Delphi Visual Control Library, the widget set every other widget set wants to be like when it grows up,) and makes them available to C and C++.

Comment: Also, C++ Builder/Delphi has existed for about as long as VB and has always been as easy to use (easier, since C++/Object Pascal are sane languages, in comparison to VB).

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't call C++ a sane language in comparison to anything. (Except maybe INTERCAL and its ilk.) But that's not what the question was about.

Comment: You have obviously not worked in VB then.

Comment: @Lundin: I have, but it's been a few years...